# template class in enclosing namespace as friend

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, clang, friend

I have code with the following basic structure

```
namespace my {
  template<typename> class A;              // forward declaration
  namespace details {
    template<typename T> class B
    {
      const T*const t;
      B(const T*x) : t(x) {}               // non-public constructor
      template<typename> friend class A;   // friend declaration
    };
  }
  template<typename T> class A
  {
    T*const t;
  public:
    A(T*x) : t(x) {}
    details::B<T> makeb() const            // offending method:
    { return details::B<T>(t); }           //   calls non-public constructor
  };
}
```

which compiled fine under gcc (4.7 & 4.8, using `-std=c++11`) and icpc (13.1), but not clang (using `-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++`), which complains about usage of a non-public constructor (when instantinating the offending method). It turns out that clang is happy if the friend declaration gives the full qualified name, as in

```
template<typename> friend class my::A;
```

Is this a bug of clang? I would have thought that any visible symbol in the enclosing namespace `my` is available *without further qualification* in the inner namespace `my::details`. What does the 2011 standard say?

Comment: Even thought this question is kind of old: There's no such thing as a forward declaration of classes. You either declare them, as noted by `template<typename> class A`, or you provide a class definition `class Foo {...}`

Comment: @SebTu A declaration (of whatever) without definition is generally referred to as a [*forward declaration*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration). This can be of functions or classes or templates for either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Clang is right:

> #### 7.3.1.2 Namespace member definitions [namespace.memdef]
>
> <sup>3</sup> Every name first declared in a namespace is a member of that namespace. If a `friend` declaration in a non-local class first declares a class, function, class template or function template the friend is a member of the innermost enclosing namespace. The name of the friend is not found by unqualified lookup (3.4.1) or by qualified lookup (3.4.3) until a matching declaration is provided in that namespace scope (either before or after the class definition granting friendship). If a friend function or function template is called, its name may be found by the name lookup that considers functions from namespaces and classes associated with the types of the function arguments (3.4.2). If the name in a `friend` declaration is neither qualified nor a *template-id* and the declaration is a function or an *elaborated-type-specifier*, **the lookup to determine whether the entity has been previously declared shall not consider any scopes outside the innermost enclosing namespace**. [ *Note:* The other forms of friend declarations cannot declare a new member of the innermost enclosing namespace and thus follow the usual lookup rules. — *end note* ] [ *Example:*

```
// Assume f and g have not yet been declared.
void h(int);
template <class T> void f2(T);
namespace A {
  class X {
    friend void f(X);         // A::f(X) is a friend
    class Y {
      friend void g();        // A::g is a friend
      friend void h(int);     // A::h is a friend
                              // ::h not considered
      friend void f2<>(int);  // ::f2<>(int) is a friend
    };
  };

  // A::f, A::g and A::h are not visible here
  X x;
  void g() { f(x); }          // definition of A::g 
  void f(X) { /* ...  */}     // definition of A::f 
  void h(int) { /* ...  */ }  // definition of A::h
  // A::f, A::g and A::h are visible here and known to be friends
}

using A::x;

void h() {
  A::f(x);
  A::X::f(x);      // error: f is not a member of A::X
  A::X::Y::g();    // error: g is not a member of A::X::Y
}
```

> — *end example* ]

Note the `// ::h not considered`.

Comment: Hmm. the `// ::h not considered` is not relevant to my case, as this is a simple non-template stand-alone method, not a template class. What exactly is a *template-id* and what an *elaborated-type-specifier* ??

Comment: A *template-id* is the `f2<>` in the example, it always has angle brackets. An *elaborated-type-specifier* is the case of your example, where the above says "function or *elaborated-type-specifier*", it is defined in §7.1.6.3.

Comment: okay thanks. I filed a bug report with gcc at http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56820

Comment: @Walter btw I compiled the source attachment from the bug report with `g++ 5.4.0`: still does not produce the required warning. I am not so familiar with the process of fixing compiler bugs but shouldn't one expect it to be updated / resolved after ~ 3 years ?

Comment: @SebTu Not necessarily. This is certainly low priority and bugzilla says it's not been fixed yet, even not assigned to anybody, nor been targeted ...